# What are the name servers for Alibaba Cloud DNS

Tags: dns-hosting, alibaba-cloud

I would like to use Alibaba Cloud Basic DNS for an existing domain, but I did not figure out how to request for name servers. It should be something like `ns1.aliyun.com`, `ns2..`

I read through the [documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/product/34269.htm?spm=a2c63.p38356.a1.2.709d108cwwOKHL) and tried to figure out but no mention of name servers nor actions what can instantiate them.

As you see in the screenshot DNS Server is empty.
[image: Instance Details of a domain in Aliyun console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/42479.htm?spm=a2c63.o282931.a3.5.45461ab0slqkhZ#concept-twj-bpd-b2b-section-oqg-zpd-b2b

You can use as well dig to query NS.

> dig @8.8.8.8 +short NS alidns.com

- ns1.aliyun.com.
- ns2.aliyun.com.
- ns3.aliyun.com.
- ns4.aliyun.com.
- ns5.aliyun.com.
- ns6.alidns.com.
- ns7.alidns.com.
- ns8.alidns.com.

Comment: Citing a source would improve this answer.

Comment: Thanks, ns[1-8].alidns.com works for me.